# Delete duplicates GPS coordinates in column in each row

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a column with gps coordinates, in each row a set of geo-polygon coordinates. Most lines have duplicate gps coordinates (complete coincidence of longitude and latitude in one column).

Example:

> MULTIPOLYGON
>   23.453411011874813 41.74245395132344
>   23.453972640029299 41.74214208390741
>   23.453977029220994 41.741827739090233
>   23.454523642352295 41.741515869012523
>   23.441100249526403 41.741203996333724
>   **23.441661846243466 41.740892121053918**
>   23.456223434003668 41.74058024317317
>   **23.441661846243466 41.740892121053918**

I need to remove duplicate coordinates (bold)

I'm using teradata 16.20.32.17

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tidy up your question a little bit that coordinates are in one column or two `longitude, latitude `?

Comment: @Tserenjamts thank you, i edit my question. Longitude and latitude in one column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Teradata function for delete duplicates GPS coordinates in cell (data type ST\_GEOMETRY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767209/teradata-function-for-delete-duplicates-gps-coordinates-in-cell-data-type-st-ge)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SimplifyPreserveTopology](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/W1AEeHO2cxTi3Sn7dtj8hg/n1%7EVPJ7YdlaY2hYaFTMsDA), it's not exactly removing duplicates, but probably close to what you want:

> Simplifies a geometry by removing points that would fall within a
> specified distance tolerance.
>
> The simplification always returns a
> valid geometry. Simplified geometries require less storage space and
> fewer spatial operations during geospatial manipulations. Consequently
> operations on simplified geometries generally perform faster. Smaller
> tolerance values result in a geometry closer to the input geometry,
> but will remove fewer vertices. Larger tolerance values will remove
> more vertices, but the resulting simplified geometry will be less
> similar to the original input.